# Which format do I need in pyvot view 'to' command

Tags: python, excel, view

I only want to display some data  in excel using the python module pyvot.

```
import xl
wb = xl.workbooks()[0]
wb.view(['Test-Fit','1exp',a,b,e], name = 'curve_fit', to = 'A1:A100')
```

Now Python raises an error:

```
ValueError: 'to' argument must be a Range, Table, or None
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a proper explanation for the data type in to. Can anyone help me with the input format?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best wishes,
Andreas

Comment: I don't work with python but I guess you need to create a range using set and then use it.

Comment: Did a quick search on the error message that you got and came across this [LINK](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10353958) it also suggests the same thing... `If "to" is a Range, the values are written to it (like Range.set, but with the header prepended)` However like i mentioned that I don't work with python so I wouldn't know how you set a range :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately, I could not figure it out with your help.